# Is My Understanding of React Reconciliation Correct?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

From what I've scraped together by looking through different tutorials all day, it seems like the way that react performs updates to the dom is through the following process.

1. User interacts with the real DOM in some way that triggers a DOM event, and the event's handler ends up fires a function that tells react to update.
2. React takes a "snapshot" of the virtual dom (which is also representative of the real dom at this point), and then proceeds to create a new virtual dom with the updated state and props.
3. React diffs the snapshot and the new virtual dom, and then only modifies parts of the dom that need to be modified to match the new virtual dom.

Is my understanding of this process correct, at least at a simplistic level?

Comment: On a higher level, your understanding is correct but there are lots of things under the hood where it uses Diffing Algorithm and compares tree nodes.
You can go through the official docs - https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html

Answer (score 0):

It's almost correct, I think the mistake here is that there is no "new virtual DOM", React
always saves/uses/reuses two copies - VDOM representations of the real DOM.

- (`A`) VDOM which helps to make changes to the real DOM (according to this VDOM, React will make the minimal changes to the DOM).
- (`B`) VDOM which represents all changes made to real DOM (what you called a "snapshot", this VDOM will be compared to `A`).

So to summary the process like you did:

0. If VDOM does not exist, create one (VDOM `A`).
1. User interacts with the real DOM in some way that triggers a DOM event, and the event's handler ends up fires a function that tells react to update.
2. React creates (or reuses) one of the VDOMs (`B`) (which is also representative of the real dom at this point).
3. React diffs VDOM `B` **with** VDOM `A`, and then only modifies parts of the VDOM (`A`) that need to be modified.
4. React updates the real DOM using VDOM `A`.

> Note for part `3.` React uses the [diff algorithm](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html), which is somewhat just comparing the element's `keys` and props (shallow comparison).